# Optimize Google Script for loop

Tags: caching, optimization, google-apps-script

I have an app script that loops through a list of individuals and then loops through a data table and puts together emails for each individual in the list and sends out a personalized e-mail to them.  However, the issue I am having currently is that the script is too slow for the number of individuals I have and I end up getting a runtime error.

Is there anyway to optimize the code?  I started to look into caching the data so that I'm not constantly making calls to the spreadsheet, but honestly that is all new to me so I'm not sure where to begin with that.

Note that I'm working off of 2 tabs in Google Sheets.  The first holds the names and email addresses and the second is a 15 column table with data.

Here is my current code:

```
function BM_Emails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("BM E-mail Data").getDataRange();
  var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("BM E-mail List").getDataRange();
  var shBody = ss.getSheetByName("E-mail Body");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var nameData = emailRange.getValues();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = emailRange.getLastRow();
  var bottEmail = shBody.getRange("A12").getValue();

  for (var i = 1; i < nameData.length; i++) {
    var rows = nameData[i];
    var emailAddress = rows[2]; 
    var empID = rows[1]; 
    var firstName = rows[3] 
    var bmLOS = rows[0] 
    var subject = "Action Requested: Overdue";
    var htmltable = "";
    var htmlmessage = "";
    var pre_table = '<!DOCTYPE html><html>' + firstName + ',<br>';
    var post_table = '</html>';

    for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      for (col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
        if (row == 0 && col == 1) {
            htmltable += '<tr><th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
        } else
        if (row == 0 && col == lastCol - 1) {
            htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th></tr>';
        } else
        if (row == 0) {
            htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
        } else
        if (data[row][0] == empID && col == 1) {
            htmltable += '<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
        } else
        if (data[row][0] == empID && col == lastCol - 1) {
            htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td></tr>';
        } else
        if (data[row][0] == empID && (col == 5 || col == 6)) {
            htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + formatCurrency('$', data[row][col]) + '</td>';
        } else
        if (data[row][0] == empID && col == 7) {
            htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + Utilities.formatDate(data[row][col], "GMT", "MM-dd-yy") + '</td>';
        } else
        if (data[row][0] == empID) {
            htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
        }
      }
    }

    htmltable += '</tbody></table>';
    htmlmessage = pre_table + htmltable + bottEmail + post_table;

    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', {
      htmlBody: htmlmessage
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: How many rows are you talking? You're already reading the data from the spreadsheet into an array, so the most obvious optimization is done. About caching - you'd cache the value of `i` using `PropertiesService` or `CacheService`, and when the outermost loop over names completes, remove the value from the storage device.

Comment: There are 500 rows for individuals (so 500 emails being sent) and it's sifting through 750 rows to create the HTML table. Never used cache before so would need to look into what you said more to make sense to me.

Comment: Any particular reason you placed the `(i)` after the final brace for the loop over `nameData`?

Comment: nope -- must be a typo -- I'll edit and remove that out

Comment: **1. How long does a single name take to execute?** You can time it, by creating a date variable (`var start = new Date().getTime()`), and then using `Logger` to print a difference after the email is sent (`Logger.log(new Date().getTime() - start);`). I wrote a snippet and your loops are quite fast already (only about 60 - 100 ms needed), so I'm not sure where your issue is. **2. Can you specify the runtime error that is being received?**

Comment: Sending mails is not a quick action, I would suggest to look at the execution transcript to see what is actually taking time... The solution might be to do it in a sequence of smaller batches that are triggered by a timer.there are a lot of posts on that subject around here.

Comment: tehhowch -- I ran it for a few e-mails and it averaged 585ms.  So if I have 500 e-mails to send that would bring me close to 5 mins.  Assuming that there will be some that probably take longer than normal, that could explain why I'm getting the error.  The error I am getting is that I'm hitting the maximum runtime (6mins).

Comment: Thanks Serge insas -- sounds like that may need to be the path I go down considering the number of e-mails is only going to get larger.  Appreciate the help from everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You have three nested loops. Without data, difficult to confirm all three are necessary or prove this solves timeout issue—BUT it does look possible to optimize the code in last two loops, by implementing the conditionals for *row* earlier, before control enters your loop for *col*. This would reduce unnecessary loops through *col*, when *row* is not a desired row for header or *empID*.

Seems like a possible optimization step worth trying.

```
function BM_Emails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("BM E-mail Data").getDataRange();
  var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("BM E-mail List").getDataRange();
  var shBody = ss.getSheetByName("E-mail Body");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var nameData = emailRange.getValues();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = emailRange.getLastRow();
  var bottEmail = shBody.getRange("A12").getValue();

  for (var i = 1; i < nameData.length; i++) {
    var rows = nameData[i];
    var emailAddress = rows[2]; 
    var empID = rows[1]; 
    var firstName = rows[3] 
    var bmLOS = rows[0] 
    var subject = "Action Requested: Overdue";
    var htmltable = "";
    var htmlmessage = "";
    var pre_table = '<!DOCTYPE html><html>' + firstName + ',<br>';
    var post_table = '</html>';

    for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      if (row == 0){// changed to ==<----------------------------------HERE
        for (col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (col == 1) {
              htmltable += '<tr><th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
          } else
          if (col == lastCol - 1) {
              htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th></tr>';
          } else {
              htmltable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#D5D8DC">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';  
          }
        }      
      }
      else if (data[row][0] == empID) {// removed ( after [0]<---------HERE
        for (col = 1; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (col == 1) {
              htmltable += '<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
          } else
          if (col == lastCol - 1) {
              htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td></tr>';
          } else
          if (col == 5 || col == 6) {
              htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + formatCurrency('$', data[row][col]) + '</td>';
          } else
          if (col == 7) {
              htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + Utilities.formatDate(data[row][col], "GMT", "MM-dd-yy") + '</td>';
          } else {
              htmltable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
          }
        }  
      }
    }

    htmltable += '</tbody></table>';
    htmlmessage = pre_table + htmltable + bottEmail + post_table;

    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', {
      htmlBody: htmlmessage
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan -- I gave this a go and compared runtimes to the original script and it was pretty similar (maybe 100ms faster but varied per run).  I think ultimately I will end up building in a trigger as suggested by Serge